# How do I find out what wireless card my Mac has?

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

I am trying to ID the wireless card on my MBP. How do I find this information? I've trying looking on [EveryMac](http://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/), but to no avail. How do I find this info?

Answer (score 17):

```
 -> About This Mac -> More Info... -> System Report...
```

Under the Network Heading, click Wi-Fi, and find `Interfaces:` on the right side of the window.  You will find your card type, firmware version, MAC address, etc.

---

The route for older MacBook Pro running OSX 10.5, 10.6...

```
 -> About This Mac -> More Info... -> Under "Network" choose "Airport"
```

Scroll down to:
"Interfaces"
"en1"
"Card Type"

Comment: Ah. So it's something like this: AirPort Extreme  (0x14E4, 0xD6)?

Comment: Yes, that's the card name itself. Below that, you'll see `Firmware Verison` which is also important to note, since that has to do with the card & performance.

Comment: Yep, what @SoFLy said

Comment: What if my Wi-Fi section is blank? I'm running 10.10.1 http://imgur.com/1v2Yvv5

Comment: @Keyslinger it sometimes takes a few seconds to load (don't ask me why)

Answer (score 6):

Using the command line:

```
ioreg -r -n ARPT
```

The line starting with `IOName` will have a value of `pciVVVV,DDDD` Where `VVVV` is the vendor ID and `DDDD` the device ID.

For example:

```
"IOName" = "pci14e4,43ba"
```

If you google those you'll find the corresponding vendor and model. The one from my example is [Broadcom BCM43602](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Broadcom_BCM943602CS).

Answer (score 6):

```
ioreg -r -n ARPT | grep IOName
```

This way you don't have to search for the right line :)

Answer (score 0):

On MacBook with Apple Silicon (M1 Pro) and macOS Ventura 13.6 the command mentioned in the other answers `ioreg -r -n ARPT | grep IOName` returned nothing. I had to adjust it to:

```bash
ioreg -r -n wlan | grep IOName
```

The output:

```
  |   "IOName" = "pci14e4,4433"
```